# Finite Quotient Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of G.
Let $G$ = $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and $H$ = $\left \{ 0 , 5 \right \}$.

Prove that $G$/$H$ $\cong$ $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$.

I am not exactly sure how to do this, our teacher barely explained these types of problems in lecture and I am lost. I do not even know exactly what $G$/$H$ is with respects to defined $G$ and $H$.

Comment: In this case, there is not much to do. The quotient group has $5$ elements, and there is up to isomorphism only one $5$-element group.

Comment: What are the elements of the Quotient Group? I am slightly confused on what it looks like/ how to find its elements.

Comment: The elements of the quotient group are cosets of $H$; they are
$$0+H=\{0,5\},\ 1+H=\{1,6\},\ 2+H=\{2,7\},\ 3+H=\{3,8\},\ 4+H=\{4,9\}.$$

Comment: So can I use that G/H is cyclic group with Order 5 and therefore it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$?

Answer (score 2):

Use the third isomorphism theorem: $H$ is the subgroups of $\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z$ generated by the class $5+10\mathbf Z$, i.e. $5\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z$.  So
$$G/H=(\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z)/(5\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z)\simeq \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z.$$